# Get what's written in the select menu

Tags: php

i have a select menu in my web page and the value is what i use to make a query in the database.

```
  <select name="Value" SIZE=1>
    <option value="'JAVA'">Langage Java 
    <option value="'PHP'">Développement WEB (PHP)
    <option value="'JAVASCRIPT'">Langage de scripts (JS)
    <option value="'PYTHON'">Programmer en Python
  </select>
<input Value="submit" align="middle" >
```

i'd like to find a way to show to the user what he have choosed, for example if i choose PYTHON i'd like to show a message telling you have choosed Programmer en Python .. and so on ..

Comment: Your question is missing what you tried, with your current PHP code.

Comment: my code is so long i just gave the part where i need explanation.

Comment: Not my -1 but your input must have type attribute. Or you can see only a textbox as default. Also size is 1 as default. no need to define it again i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser won't send that information to the server.

Since you (presumably) wrote the HTML in the first place, you can keep a record of what values are associated with what labels.

This is usually done using a database, but you could hard code it into an associative array into the script.

Once you have a record, you can look up the submitted value in your data store.

Answer (score 1):

did yo try this

```
<?php
  $nom = "have choosed ".$_GET['Value'];
  echo $nom;
?>
```

Comment: i know how to get that but that's not really what i want =) thank you anyway ,

Comment: @KirkERW i don't if that is what you want, but that is what you asked (désolé). If you want something else then you must modify the question

Answer (score 1):

Forms are for collecting information from people in order to process some operations. Echo'ing the form's input data may be the first step to learn what we have.

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST["Value"])) 
        echo "You've chosen " . $_POST["Value"];
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <select name="Value" size="1">
            <option value="JAVA">Langage Java</option> 
            <option value="PHP">Développement WEB (PHP)</option>
            <option value="JAVASCRIPT">Langage de scripts (JS)</option>
            <option value="PYTHON">Programmer en Python</option>
          </select>
        <input Value="submit" type = "submit" align="middle" > 
    </form>
```

Comment: to whom gives -1: This code was tested before typed here. What is your problem?

Comment: It was undoubtedly the OP who didn't like the fact that you couldn't read his mind and decide what he was really asking, despite the poor wording of his question. +1

Comment: +1 because i still think this is a valid answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code   
 <?php 
    echo 'You have selected'.$_GET['value'];
    ?>
```

Comment: That same thing was literally posted here already more than 20 minutes ago...